# How to fail the ant script, if exec task fails

Tags: ant, scripting, exit

I am executing ant script in windows. In that consider that, i am executing `dir` command in `exec` task as below

```
<target name="dummy">
  <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/C DIRR"/>
  </exec>
  <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/C cd /d c:\temp"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Here I have given `DIRR` instead of `DIR`, this execution will fail. but the ant build is not failing. Its showing the error message as `dirr is not recognised as internal or external command` and the next command `cd /d c:\temp` also got executed. I want the ant script execution has to be stopped once error message comes.

I want to this script has to stop executing if error occurs in any one of the exec command. `failonerror` is also not helping. How to fail the ant build, if exec fails.

Note : I am using ant 1.8.2

Comment: `build:
     [exec] 'DIRR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     [exec] operable program or batch file. 

BUILD FAILED`Works just fine at my pc. I am not sure what you are getting.

Comment: Can you provide the whole build file? I run your example and it works fine at my pc. ant 1.8.2

Comment: @FailedDev Modified my question.

Comment: It still works as expected, i.e. it fails on the first error and the script stops exactly there.

Comment: @rajaashok  The sample works also for me as you wish - it stops after first call. Ant version: 1.8.2. You can fix misprint in your post:  <target name="dummy">.

Comment: @rajaashok Something new from this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, that there are *two* levels of execution here:

- Ant calls `cmd.exe`.
- `cmd.exe` executes `DIRSS`.

You see, if the the second step fails, this does not necessarily mean, that `cmd.exe` does propagate the error back to Ant. This might be more obvious if the mentally replace the well-known `cmd.exe` with something "innocent" like `foo.exe`.

So the next step is to explore, why the second step behaves differently on your machine than on the machines of the commentators of your question. After that riddle is solved, you can get back to the Ant question.

A first step might be this: Open a new shell window and try

```
> cmd /c dir
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%

> cmd /c dir nonexisting-directory
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%

> cmd /c dirr
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Also tell us the version of your OS.

Comment: I have never seen something failing like this. I mean it should fail on all - or none windows machines unless some magic is being done.

Comment: @FailedDev: In the end the "magic part" turns out to be a `dirr.exe` somewhere in the path :-) I would ROTFL.

Comment: +1 if this is the reason. :) I will observe this question closely. I am using ant like nuts but have yet to see such an error!